Android Media3: How to add seek buttons to the media notification?
After spending an entire week trying to understand this unbelievably complicated library, I am at my wits' end. I am convinced that there is an out-of-the-box solution for this media notification UI that's in pretty much every major app with media playback these days. It has seek forward and backward buttons, a playback speed button, and a favorite button:
I have followed these instructions exactly, and there has been no change to my notification, which looks like this instead. Just a previous track button: 
I have read this issue, where a developer admits that this is complicated (and promises to document it, lol) but I do not understand the solution he explains.
I am not using a PlayerNotificationManager.
Here's what I have so far, which does not work. In my PlaybackService:
    private val back = CommandButton.Builder()
            .setEnabled(true)
            .setIconResId(androidx.media3.session.R.drawable.media3_notification_seek_back)
            .setDisplayName("Seek Back")
            .setPlayerCommand(Player.COMMAND_SEEK_BACK)
            .build()
    private val forward = CommandButton.Builder()
            .setEnabled(true)
            .setIconResId(androidx.media3.session.R.drawable.media3_notification_seek_forward)
            .setDisplayName("Seek Forward")
            .setPlayerCommand(Player.COMMAND_SEEK_FORWARD)
            .build()
    private val buttons = ImmutableList.of(back, forward)

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val intent = packageManager!!.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)!!
            .let { sessionIntent ->
                PendingIntent.getActivity(this, SESSION_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE, sessionIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
            }
        _session = MediaSession.Builder(this, buildPlayer())
            .setSessionActivity(intent)
            .setCustomLayout(buttons)
            .setCallback(CustomMediaSessionCallback())
            .build()
        setListener(PlaybackServiceListener()) // irrelevant to this question
    }

    private inner class CustomMediaSessionCallback: MediaSession.Callback {
      override fun onConnect(
          session: MediaSession,
          controller: MediaSession.ControllerInfo
      ): MediaSession.ConnectionResult {
          val sessionCommands = MediaSession.ConnectionResult.DEFAULT_PLAYER_COMMANDS.buildUpon()
              .add(back.playerCommand)
              .add(forward.playerCommand)
              .build()
          return MediaSession.ConnectionResult.AcceptedResultBuilder(session)
              .setCustomLayout(buttons)
              .setAvailablePlayerCommands(sessionCommands)
              .build()
      }
    }

In my ViewModel, I'm creating the SessionToken and MediaController:
private val sessionToken =
        SessionToken(getApplication(), ComponentName(getApplication(), PlaybackService::class.java))
private val controllerFuture = MediaController.Builder(getApplication(), sessionToken).buildAsync()

Once the MediaController is ready, I add the MediaItem and start playback.
with(controller!!) {
    playWhenReady = true
    setMediaItem(mediaItem)
    prepare()
}

To be clear, absolutely nothing changes if I remove .setCustomLayout(buttons) and .setCallback(CustomMediaSessionCallback()) from my MediaSession.Builder. It has no effect.
I do get a warning in logcat: "Couldn't find a unique registered media button receiver in the given context." I searched for this string in the media3 repo, and it does not appear there.
Can anyone help me? Thanks!

What's the default setup. From what I read, all of these actions are available by default

@gtxtreme I've edited my post to include how I'm creating the SessionToken and MediaController in the ViewModel. If these actions are available by default, maybe there is something missing from how I construct MediaItems or something. The docs are extremely unhelpful regardless...

An update! I have learned that CommandButton.Builder.setPlayerCommand() is for the in-app PlayerView, not the notification. For the notification, we need to call setSessionCommand() with our custom command string. With this change, I get forward and back seeking functionality, but it appends both icons to the right of the seek bar. I have found styles and layout files in the media3 repo corresponding to these buttons (eg. ExoStyledControls.Button.Center.FfwdWithAmount). They seem to be only for in-app UI. I am completely losing my mind trying to understand how to do this very simple thing

Further adventures down the debugging rabbit hole... I suspect these buttons are unavailable because the Player Command COMMAND_GET_CURRENT_MEDIA_ITEM is not available after the MediaItems have been set. Now trying to figure out why... But isCurrentMediaItemSeekable() returns false unless that Command is available.

I finally found a codebase on GitHub with the notification UI I'm trying to achieve, and it looks like people really are rolling this themselves. Seems completely bonkers to me that this isn't available out of the box, but I'm done digging into the guts of this garbage library for now. Time to build the layout from scratch and move on with my life.
If I am wrong, please do let me know, and I'll be happy to accept a better answer.

"I finally found a codebase on GitHub" - could you link it, please?

A bit late, I believe you are missing MediaSession.setAvailableCommands.
you are right seekForward and seekBackward are not out of the box in notifications anymore, I believe since android 12 they gutted it out.
This is one of the resources I followed;
and google's demo, where they added a custom button to enable/disable shuffle mode.
lastly my work (though it's adding customActions 2b used with react native).
